# Route traffic to a destination to another destination using iptables

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, iptables

How to route traffic to a destination to another destination and receive response using iptables

I have two vps on cloud. Lets say VPS-A and VPS-B.

If a request to 8.8.8.8 generated from VPN-A, I want to route that request to VPS-B. Then VPS-B should accept that request and return the response.

what are the iptable rules to achieve this?

Comment: routing is done with **ip route** commands, not iptables.  Iptables is a manages the firewall.  What you may be looking for is some kind of **vpn** or proxy.

Comment: You are right, VPS-B is installed with openswan and vpn tunnel is up and running. VPS-A is a client machine of VPS-B. Since both were remote machines, I cant set the gateway to VPS-B with ip route command. So I'm looking for some iptable rules to forward some specific request to VPS-B.

Answer (score 0):

You said you need only iptables part. OK. Here it is (quite simple). This must be on VPS-B:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -d 8.8.8.8 -j ACCEPT
```

These two rules will accept all traffic from and to 8.8.8.8 to pass trough VPS-B. Routing is for you.

Comment: what about iptable rules in VPS-A to forward a specific request to VPS-B ?

Comment: You did not say anything about _specific request_, you wanted only acceptance from VPS_B. The rest is routing.